# Warnings are not showing in Laravel 5.1

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5.1

I am new to Laravel, and I want it to show all warnings, notices and errors.

I searched a lot and tried many things but nothing seems to work.
In `.env` I have

```
APP_ENV=local
APP_DEBUG=true
```

in my controller I echo a non-defined variable

```
echo $undefined;
```

but still it is not showing any warning or error, it just runs perfectly and also there is no entry in the `laravel.log` file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In my case problem was of some directory permission.
Allow recursive 777 permission to folders `/vendor` and `/storage`
And it works.

Answer (score 1):

check your app.php  in config/app.php

```
'debug' => env('APP_DEBUG', true)
```

is true or false ?

Comment: yes its written, and i tried both 'true' and 'false', not working.

Comment: if you try to visit the undefined  route then what page you get ??
warnings ??

Comment: NotFoundHttpException in RouteCollection.php line 143: i think its a fatal error so it showing it.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like at the php.ini level you have silencing of errors. Search in there for *error_reporting* and have it set to be something along the lines of

`error_reporting = E_ALL & ~E_DEPRECATED & ~E_STRICT`

You should then start to see the errors again.

Comment: in `php.ini` it's written exactly. and outside of laravel it working fine but problem is within laravel.

Answer (score -1):

For the time I just do this.

Every Controller in Laravel 5.1 extends "Controller", So i just Added

```
error_reporting(E_ALL);
```

in constructor of this this. And now laravel Showing warnings in Laravel Format with Stack Trace.